# How to deploy webpart in other than custom folder in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

Normally custom webparts comes under custom folder in webpart gallery.
I want to make that available in user defined folder. any one know how to do this..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, you can open the webparts Elements.xml file.  Within this file you should see the property tag named Group.  Change the value of this property from "Custom" to whatever you desire.

Eg

```
<Property Name="Group" Value="ENTER NAME OF GROUP" />
```